# How To Update The Database Row If The userID has autoincrement Property

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I am going to update the coeds_user table which has userid autoincrement property whenever insert occurs, it automatically gets autoincremented by 1 and then inserts the corresponding data in rest of the field.So far i have succeded in inserting the row, but my problem is how to update this row when userid is autoincrement, can you please let me know how to implement the update function for autoincremented userid , thank you in advance.
insert_search.php

```
<?php
$user="root";
$server="localhost";
$password="";
$db="coedsproddb1";
$dbconn= mysql_connect($server,$user,$password);
mysql_select_db($db,$dbconn);

?>
<html>
<head><title>Insert</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<header> <img src="images/ipoint.png" class="logo" /> USER REGISTRATION</header>
<div class="container">
<h1 style="text-align:center">ADDING THE USER DETAILS</h1>
<style>
#display {
color:red;
font-size:12px;
text-align:center;
}
.logo {
padding:5px;
float:left;
}
header {
background-color:#074e7c;
height:60px;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
color:white;
font-size:40px;

}
#wrap {
text-align:center;
}
</style>
<form name="useradd" id="useradd" action="#" method="post">
<table align='center' border='1'>

    <tr>

           <td> <label for="userName">UserName</label></td>
            <td ><input id="userName" name="userName"  type="text" /></td>


        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td> <label for="userEmail">Email</label></td>
        <td ><input id="userEmail" name="userEmail" type="text"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="userPassword">password</label></td>
            <td ><input id="userPassword" name="userPassword" type="password" /></td>


        </tr>

        <tr>

           <td> <label for="regDate">RegistrationDate</label></td>
           <td ><input id="regDate" name="regDate" type="text" />  </td>

        </tr>






        <tr>

           <td> <label for="ogeeid">Ogeeid</label></td>
           <td ><input id="ogeeid" name="ogeeid" type="text" />  </td>

        </tr>

        </table>


<br>
<div id="wrap">
<input type="submit" name="add" value="add" id="add">
</div>
</form>
<div id="display">
</div>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$( "#regDate" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
});
$("#add").click(function(e){


    var userName = $("#userName").val();
    var userEmail = $("#userEmail").val();
    var userPassword = $("#userPassword").val();
    var regDate = $("#regDate ").val();
    var d=$.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", new Date(regDate));

    var ogeeid = $("#ogeeid").val();





    var dataString='userName='+userName+'&userEmail='+userEmail+'&userPassword='+userPassword+'&regDate='+d+'&ogeeid='+ogeeid;
    alert(dataString);
    if(userName==""||userEmail==""||userPassword==""||regDate==""||ogeeid=="")
    {
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML="Please Enter The Fields";
    }


    else
    {
    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "insert.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(result){
                //alert("submitted"+result);
                $('#display').html(result);

                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert(xhr.status);
                        alert(thrownError);
                }
                });
                e.preventDefault(); 
                }
                });



                });
                </script>





</body>
</html>
```

insert.php

```
<html>
<head><title>Insertion</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="display">
<?php
include('db.php');




$userName=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userName']);
$userEmail=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userEmail']);
$userPassword=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userPassword']);

$regDate1=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['regDate']);
 $regDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($regDate1));



function generateCode($characters) 
{
    $possible = '23456789abcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz';
    $code = '';
    $i = 0;
    while ($i < $characters) { 
        $code .= substr($possible, mt_rand(0, strlen($possible)-1), 1);
        $i++;
    }
    return $code;
}

$registration_key=generateCode(10);

$ogeeid=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ogeeid']);

$str="insert into coeds_user(userName,userEmail,userPassword,regDate,registration_key,ogeeid) values('$userName','$userEmail','$userPassword','$regDate','$registration_key',$ogeeid)";
echo $str;
$query=mysql_query($str);
if($query)
{
$display="Success";
}
else
{
$display= "Failed";
}
echo $display;

?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you still using Mysql **mysql extension is deprecated**

Answer (score 0):

You are updating user detail, now you know the id field of row. You can present update form with hidden input field with name="id" and value="user_row_id". Then write simple SQL update query in your code.

Comment: update coeds_user set blah blah where userId=$user_row_id;? iss this correct?